# the implied meaning of 'Virtue's admired - and shivers with the cold.'

Tags: meaning

Can you tell me the implied meaning of the quote below by Juvenal?

> Virtue's admired - and shivers with the cold.

Virture should be admired, that's OK. 
But why does it shivers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a quote that not only exists but is accurately presented!

The Latin is

> Probitas laudatur et alget.

Literally,

> Honesty (or uprightness) is praised and gets cold.

Juvenal was a great lamenter of lost Roman civic virtues, and he's saying outright (not implying) that his fellow citizens speak highly of virtues but neglect them in the performance. A loose translation would be

> We speak warmly of virtues but give them the cold shoulder in practice.

Comment: Right. You could express the same idea from the pragmatist's (rather than the moralist's) perspective by saying "A good reputation doesn't pay the rent."